# Copying a file and uploading it in Sharepoint with VBS

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, vbscript, uploading

I am trying to code a VB script to copy a pdf file from a network drive and paste it in the Sharepoint.

I have mapped the Sharepoint network to my computer, but still it does not work.
I have searched a lot in the internet for a solution, but so far nothing has worked.

Does anyone know what is my mistake? Is the problem in my path?
Thanks

```
Dim FSO 
 Dim FromPath 
  Dim ToPath 
   Dim Datum

Datum = Format(Now() - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy")
ToPath = "\\share.\DavWWWRoot\sites\MySharepoint"
FromPath = "\Report_" & Right(Datum) & ".pdf"

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
```

Everytime I run it, I get the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected statement

Comment: This appears to be VBA code. VBScript does not support named parameters. Try `FSO.CopyFolder FromPath, ToPath`.

Comment: Also, the `Format()` function does not exist, look for alternatives with regard to how to format dates in VBScript, there are plenty of examples.